# Sweetalert2 redirection

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have a php page where I can enter a number in a texfield. If the number entered is higher than the credit the user has, then I have to show an error message. When the user clicks on the button to send the form, I go to makeTransfer.php and I do several checks in here. If, as I said, the user has not credit enough I want to show him an error message using SweetAlert2 and then redirect him to the previous page (let's call it cashier). At the moment, I can show the alert but I'm unable to redirect him.

Here is the code:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("WOW!","Message!","error");';
echo '});</script>';
```

I just want to show the alert, and as soon as the user clicks on Accept button, redirects him to cashier.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, solved the problem. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
swal({ 
  title: "Error",
   text: "wrong user or password",
    type: "error" 
  }).then(function() {
    // Redirect the user
    window.location.href = "cashier.php";
    })});
</script>
```

Worked my a** off, but it paid off :). Thanks everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
swal({
  title: 'Redirect',
  text: "Message",
  type: 'success',
}).then(function (result) {
  if (true) {
    window.location = "cashier.php";
  }
})
```

like this it will redirect to cahsier.php in that same directory as it is in right now if the if returns true, you can also leave it away

Comment: Hi Nico, thanks for you reply. I tried like you said but it doesn't even show the alert window :(. I´m trying to gather it in a .php script so it seems that if I don't implement it inside the echos, it is not showing :S. I tried like this: 

`<script type="text/javascript"> 
 swal({
  title: 'Redirect',
  text: "Message",
  type: 'success',
}).then(function (result) {
  if (true) {
    window.location = "cashier.php";
  }
 })
</script>`

But it is not working. I´m importing sweetalert2 libraries...correct?

Answer (score 2):

```js
Swal.fire({
    type: 'error',
    title: 'Oops...',
    confirmButtonText: 'Shopping',
    text: 'There is no items on your cart.',
    footer: '',
    showCloseButton: true
})
.then(function (result) {
    if (result.value) {
        window.location = "Default.aspx";
    }
})
```

trust me above script is work for me! thank you

Comment: Can you please add context and detail to your solution? Why does this work? This way other people can use this answer even with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
swal({
  title: 'WOW',
  text: "Message",
  type: 'error',
}).then(function (result) {
  if (result.value) {
    window.location = "/cashier.php";
  }
})
```

Comment: Hey zakrzu, thanks a lot for your reply. 

I tried like this:

`echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("WOW!","Message!","error");';

echo '}).then(function (result) { if (result.value) { window.location = "/cashier.php";}});</script>';`

It shows the alert but still doesn't redirect :(

Comment: add this and check console:
if (result.value) { console.log(result);window.location = "/cashier.php";}

Comment: I got this error: Uncaught TypeError: setTimeout(...).then is not a function :S

Comment: add then to swal, not to steTimeout

Comment: hi @zakrzu, I didn't understand your last comment...can you please explain? Sorry about that :( and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    Swal.fire({
        title: "Success!", //Text can be changed example Success!
        html: "I will close in <strong></strong> seconds.<br/><br/>",//Text can be changed
        type: "success", //Text can be changed example success, warning, danger
        timer: 3000, //Set the time interval (in milliseconds).
        timerProgressBar: true,
        didOpen: () => {
            const content = Swal.getHtmlContainer()
            const $ = content.querySelector.bind(content)
            Swal.showLoading()
            timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
                Swal.getHtmlContainer().querySelector('strong')
                    .textContent = (Swal.getTimerLeft() / 1000)
                    .toFixed(0)
            }, 100)
        },
        willClose: () => {
            clearInterval(timerInterval)
        },
        showConfirmButton: false, //Turn off confirmation button, if true, it will show ok button, click again.
    }).then(function() {
        window.location.href = "index.php";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me

```js
function NotificationMessage(message, type = 'success', url = false) {
    const Toast = Swal.mixin({
        toast: true,
        position: 'top-end',
        showConfirmButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Ko`rish <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>',
        timer: 5000,
        preConfirm: () => {
            return window.location.href = url;
        },
        timerProgressBar: true,
    })

    Toast.fire({
        icon: type,
        title: message
    })
}

NotificationMessage('Qo`shildi', 'success', 'https://www.google.com/');
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```